# jquery how can i find empty space where there is no element will not intereptable?

Tags: jquery, ipad

I am supposed to make a event to my ipad, onclick to show a navigation bar. but while the user touch on the element which contains the link ('a') or any other element have the function with should not affect by this touch event... what is the best way to do this? i am sorry i don't have any idea about this.

it means, i need to find that, the person clicking on the spot has not any other element or which the elemnent has not event with this... i am right? how can i find this and attach a click to empty areas?

example code :

```
$("body").delegate('body > div','click', function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
       NewDataApi.exec('viewport','touch', {'number': '0'}); 
    })
```

this is what i wrote. but in case there is a "a" element which is clicked, it call the above function, instead take user to new window..

i am sorry if i am not explained properly... any help i am in critical position to fix this...

thanks

Comment: its possible to create invisible divs with absolute position and attach click events, does this help? please provide more details thanks

Comment: no, it will not... for example i say there is a div, it contains href, and so on. while the user moving or touch with href based "a" element it should take him to new window. in case there is no element apart from div, then it should show the navigation bar triggering function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answers your question, let me edit it if I have not understood correctly

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#123").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        alert("123");
    })
    $("#123 > a").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().unbind('click');
        window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    })
});
</script>

<div id="123" style="width:100px;border:1px solid #F00;">
<a href="http://www.google.com">###</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onClick event of the page itself:

```
document.onclick=(function(){ window.alert('clicked'); });
```